# IExceptionHandlerFeature always return null

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-middleware

I have a custom middleware for handling exceptions globally. In the catch block, I have following code

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            try
            {
              .....
}
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    ....
       var error= HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
    ....
    }
}
```

I'm explicitly throwing different kind of exceptions from Controller action methods for testing purpose.
But Get() always return null and so is error.
How can I resolve this issue as I need to fetch exception type in custom middleware?

**Note**: If I use default UseExceptionHandler() middleware, Get() is returning proper value having exception type.

Comment: how are you adding custom middleware to pipeline.

Comment: and by the way why do you want add your own middleware when it is already provided.

Comment: To handle exceptions and need to log error to the records.

Comment: the question was why do you want **custom** middleware when it is already given by .NET Core. use **UseExceptionHandler**  and you just need to add the code for formatting the exception before returning to caller. [example](https://medium.com/@niteshsinghal85/how-i-have-handled-exception-globally-in-asp-net-core-api-7b8c2603af72)

Comment: If you throw exception in the action and want to get the exception detail in middleware, I think you just need add  `await _next(context);` in `try` block and you can get the exception in `catch` block by `ex` here: `catch(Exception ex)`.

Answer (score 3):

For what I have experienced, the UseDeveloperExceptionPage middleware removes the IExceptionHandlerFeature.

Comment: Looks like this is a .NET 7 bug, fixed in .NET 8.